# How to set programmatically "allow all devices to connect" in Tethering and Wi-Fi hotspot Settings

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have developed a Android application to control Tethering and Wi-Fi hotspot Settings in the device. I was able to do some important tasks such as turn on-off Wi-Fi hotspot, chage the AP name, Shared key ect.. But still i was not able to find a method to control "allow all devices to connect" option. If there any method please help me..

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a stock Android setting, so I don't think you'll find any sanctioned way of doing so. What device do you see this option on?

Comment: Most of the Samsung Devices have that option. I was working on a samsung Galaxy note 10.1

Comment: Most likely it's a feature created by Samsung that isn't in the Android SDK, so you'd have to do this with reflection somehow. Without the source available, you'd have to do some work to figure out if there's any way to set that without being a system application. Even if it is, it would only be something available on Samsung devices, and not all of them.